# Handling Ktor Exception for API calls

Tags: android, ktor-client

I have a use case like I want to handle the Ktor exceptions in a single place instead of each API call, Say I am having more than one API calls in this case I shouldn't duplicate the code for handling exception ... My code looks like below

```
try {
    val modelResponse = client.get(API) {
        header("Authorization", token)
    }.body<ModelCLass>()
    response(modelResponse)
} catch (cause: HttpRequestTimeoutException) { // If we have any Time out Exception
    Log.d(TAG, "ConnectTimeoutException failure: $cause")
} catch (cause: IOException) { // Network failure is handled
    Log.d(TAG, "IOException failure: $cause")
} catch (clientException: ClientRequestException) { // If we have client side issue like invalid request (Or) data miss
    val exceptionResponse = clientException.response
    if(exceptionResponse.status == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
        // un authorized
    } else {
      // Api Error
    }
} catch (cause: Exception) { // If other general exception
    Log.d(TAG, "General Exception failure: $cause")wrong")
}
```

How can I write a common function for handling exception in this case of catch statements